# Calling from 3rd party device (with "Videophone" capabilities) to Linphone(Desktop) displays video while calling Linphone(Browser) does not

Tags: sip, voip, linphone

I'm trying to write a proof of concept to show that a 3rd party hardware device with "Videophone" capabilities can call a web application on the same LAN.  At the recommendation of the manufacturer of the device, I'm using linphone.

Firstly, Linphone for Windows works perfectly **(After enabling H263 under video codecs)**  So to clarify, the 3rd party device makes use of the H263 video codec.

Linphone **for the browser** using my proof of concept, shows video when called from linphone for windows but NOT when called from the 3rd part device.

**First Problem**

After some digging through https://www.linphone.org/docs/linphone-web/external-LinphoneCore.html and looking at the results of "core.videoCodecs" I noticed 
that the only video codec returned was VP8.

After more digging, the x-linphone-web plugin does not include all codecs by default.  So I recompiled the plugin with support for "H263" enabled.  "core.videoCodecs" 
now returned with "H263" as one of the codecs.  At this point, there is still no video when I call from the 3rd party device to my proof of concept.

**Other things I've tried:**

1. **Manipulate linphone core parameters**. *(videoPort, videoPolicy, ...)*
2. **Accept calls in different ways**. Using acceptCall, acceptCallWithParams, acceptEarlyMedia followed by acceptCall.
3. I noticed that linphone for windows exports its configuration to a linphonerc file.  **Tried to initialise the linphone core using the same parameters an linphone for windows**

   3.1 Tried using core.init('URI to file using the format file:///C:/test.linphonerc'); This caused an invalid URI error.

   3.2 Tried using core.init('URI to file using the format 'local:///test.linphonerc'); This didn't cause an error but created new file C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Temp\linphone-web\8d89-653a-c164-9d79\test.linphonerc

   3.3 Tried creating the file in code using newLpConfig('local:///test.linphonerc') then initialising using core.init('local:///test.linphonerc').  newLpConfig writes to a new folder in C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Temp\linphone-web\ and init tries to read from yet another new folder in C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Temp\linphone-web\
4. **Looking at wireshark logs** to see the difference between calling linphone for windows and calling proof of concept with linphone browser from 3rd party device.

   4.1 Linphone(Windows) replies to the SIP Invite with a "101 Dialog Establishment" while Linphone(Browser) replies with a "100 Trying"

   4.2 When the "answer call" button is pressed, Linphone(Windows) replies with "200 OK" that includes a SDP media description **"Media Description, name and address (m): video 9078 RTP/AVP 34"** while Linphone(Browser) replies with **"200 OK" with a media description "Media Description, name and address (m): video 0 RTP/AVP 0"**

   4.3 On answer, Linphone(Windows) replies with **"200 OK"** that includes a SDP media attribute **"Media Attribute (a): rtpmap:34 H263/90000"** while Linphone(Browser) replies with **"200 OK"** without a video media attribute.

Incase someone would like to see the code.

linphone.html

---

```
<html>

    <head>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="linphone.js"></script>  
    </head>

    <body onload="initLinphoneCore()" style="background:#000000; font-family : Arial; font-size: 12;">

        <object id="core" type="application/x-linphone-web" width="0" height="0">
            <param name="onload" value='initLinphoneCore()'>
        </object>

        <div style="width : 640px; height : 480px; position : absolute; top : 30%; left : 30%; right : 30%; background : #EEEEEE;">                         

            <div id="status" style="position:relative; height:30px; font-size:18px;top:0px; background:#888888; color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;"></div>
            <div id="videoContainer1" style="position:relative; top: 25%; left:25%;" ></div>

            <div style="position:absolute; width : 100%; height:30px; font-size:18px; bottom:0px; text-align: right; background : #333333;">
                <input type="button" OnClick="answerCall()" value="Answer Call">
            </div>      

        </div>      

    </body> 
</html>
```

linphone.js

---

```
var CallStatusIdle = 0;
var CallStatusIncomingReceived = 1;
var CallStatusConnected = 6;
var CallStatusStreamsRunning = 7;
var CallStatusError = 12;
var CallStatusEnd = 13;

var currentCall;
var currentCallStatus = CallStatusIdle;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name : addEvent
// Desc : Register to be notified of an event.
// param obj :
// param name :
// param func :
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function addEvent(obj, name, func) 
{
    if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on"+name, func);
    } else {
        obj.addEventListener(name, func, false); 
    }
}   

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name : updateStatus
// Desc : Function that display some text in a html element.
// param id :
// param value :
// param bgColour:
// param fgColour:
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function updateStatus(id, value, bgColour, fgColour)
{
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML= value;
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = bgColour;
    document.getElementById(id).style.color = fgColour;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name : getCore
// Desc : Get a reference to linphone core.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function getCore()
{
    return document.getElementById('core');
}                       
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Title : initLinphoneCore.
// Desc : Initialise the linphone core.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function initLinphoneCore()
{       
    var core = getCore();

    addEvent(core, "callStateChanged", onCallStateChanged);

    /*
        Initial attempt was to initialise using core.init();
        Haven't managed to get that working so attempt "n" is to specify the configuration as exported using
        the windows desktop version of linphone.
    */


    var config = core.newLpConfig("local:///config.linphonerc");
    config.cleanSection("rtp");
    config.setString('rtp', 'download_ptime', "0");
    config.setString('rtp', 'audio_rtp_port', "7078");
    config.setString('rtp', 'video_rtp_port', "9078");
    config.setString('rtp', 'audio_jitt_comp', "60");
    config.setString('rtp', 'video_jitt_comp', "60");
    config.setString('rtp', 'nortp_timeout', "30");
    config.setString('rtp', 'audio_adaptive_jitt_comp_enabled', "1");
    config.setString('rtp', 'video_adaptive_jitt_comp_enabled', "1");
    config.setString('rtp', 'audio_dscp', "0x2e");
    config.setString('rtp', 'video_dscp', "0x2e");              
    config.cleanSection("sip");
    config.setString('sip', 'media_encryption', "none");
    config.setString('sip', 'default_proxy', "-1");
    config.setString('sip', 'sip_port', "5062");
    config.setString('sip', 'sip_tcp_port', "0");
    config.setString('sip', 'sip_tls_port', "0");
    config.setString('sip', 'use_info', "1");
    config.setString('sip', 'guess_hostname', "1");
    config.setString('sip', 'inc_timeout', "30");
    config.setString('sip', 'in_call_timeout', "0");
    config.setString('sip', 'delayed_timeout', "4");
    config.setString('sip', 'use_ipv6', "0");
    config.setString('sip', 'register_only_when_network_is_up', "1");
    config.setString('sip', 'register_only_when_upnp_is_ok', "1");
    config.setString('sip', 'dscp', "0x1a");
    config.cleanSection("video");
    config.setString('video', 'display', "1");
    config.setString('video', 'capture', "1");
    config.setString('video', 'automatically_initiate', "1");
    config.setString('video', 'automatically_accept', "1");
    config.setString('video', 'show_local', "0");
    config.setString('video', 'self_view', "0");
    config.setString('video', 'size', "svga");
    // config.setString('video', 'device', "Removed for SO Question");  
    config.cleanSection("net");
    config.setString('net', 'download_bw', "0");
    config.setString('net', 'upload_bw', "0");
    config.setString('net', 'adaptive_rate_control', "1");
    config.setString('net', 'firewall_policy', "0");
    config.setString('net', 'mtu', "1300");     
    config.cleanSection("sound");
    // config.setString('sound', 'playback_dev_id', "Removed for SO Question");
    // config.setString('sound', 'ringer_dev_id', "Removed for SO Question");
    // config.setString('sound', 'capture_dev_id', "Removed for SO Question");
    config.setString('sound', 'echocancellation', "0");
    config.setString('sound', 'mic_gain_db', "0.000000");
    config.setString('sound', 'local_ring', "C:\Program Files (x86)\Linphone\share\sounds\linphone\rings\oldphone.wav");
    config.setString('sound', 'playback_gain_db', "0.000000");  
    config.cleanSection("video_codec_0");
    config.setString('video_codec_0', 'mime', "H263");
    config.setString('video_codec_0', 'rate', "90000");
    config.setString('video_codec_0', 'enabled', "1");
    config.setString('video_codec_0', 'recv_fmtp', "");     
    config.cleanSection("video_codec_1");
    config.setString('video_codec_1', 'mime', "VP8");
    config.setString('video_codec_1', 'rate', "90000");
    config.setString('video_codec_1', 'enabled', "1");      
    config.cleanSection("video_codec_2");
    config.setString('video_codec_2', 'mime', "H263-1998");
    config.setString('video_codec_2', 'rate', "90000");
    config.setString('video_codec_2', 'enabled', "1");
    config.setString('video_codec_2', 'recv_fmtp', "1;QCIF=1");                     

    // Write configuration file:
    var configFileSynch = config.sync();
    if ( configFileSynch !== 0 ) {      
        console.log( 'Failed to write configuration file.' );
        return;     
    }

    // Initialise core:
    var coreInit = core.init( 'local:///config.linphonerc' );
    if ( coreInit !== 0 ) 
    {
        console.log( 'Failed to initialise core.' );
        return;
    }

    // Setup core logging.
    core.logHandler = function( level, message ) 
    {
        window.console.log(message);
    }   

    // Start main loop:
    core.iterateEnabled = true; 

    updateStatus ( 'status', 'Linphone Core Initialised', "#888888", '#FFFFFF');
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name : onCallStateChanged
// Desc : On notification of call status, decide on the logic to perform.
// param event : The event that triggered all of this.
// param call : The call object that had its state changed.
// param state : The new state of the call.
// param message : A description of the call state.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function onCallStateChanged(event, call, state, message)
{
    try {

        // Keep a reference for later use:
        currentCall = call;
        currentCallStatus = state;

        // Log new call state:
        window.console.log('Call state changed : ' + state);

        if ( CallStatusIncomingReceived === state ) 
        {           
            updateStatus('status', message, "#0000AA", '#FFFFFF');                      
            document.getElementById('videoContainer1').innerHTML=  "<object id='remoteVideo1' type='application/x-linphone-web-video' style='display: inline; width: 320px; height: 240px; position:absolute'><param name='onload' value='onLoadVideo1' /><param name='magic' value='1' /></object>";                       
        }               
        else if ( CallStatusConnected === state )
        {
            updateStatus('status', message, "#000000", '#FFFFFF');
        }       
        else if( CallStatusStreamsRunning === state )
        {       
            updateStatus('status', message, "#00AA00", '#FFFFFF');                          
        }
        else if( CallStatusEnd === state )
        {   
            updateStatus('status', message, "#000000", '#FFFFFF');      
        }
        else if( CallStatusError === state ) 
        {
            updateStatus('status', message, "#440000", '#FFFFFF');
        }                       

    } 
    catch (err)
    {
        var msg = "There was an error during call status change : " + err.message;
        console.log ( msg );
        updateStatus ( 'status', msg, "#000000", '#FFFFFF');
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name : answerCall
// Desc : User clicked button to answer call.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function answerCall() 
{
    try {

        core.acceptCall ( currentCall) ;
    } 
    catch (err) 
    {
        var msg = "There was an error while answering call : " + err.message;
        console.log ( msg );
        updateStatus ( 'status', msg, "#000000", '#FFFFFF');                
    }
}       

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name : onLoadVideo1
// Desc : Initialise video parameters after x-linphone-web-video injected and loaded.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
function onLoadVideo1() {   
    var v = document.getElementById('remoteVideo1');
    core.videoPolicy.automaticallyAccept = true;        
    core.videoDisplayEnabled = true; 
    core.nativeVideoWindowId = v.window;                    

}
```

---

***Any idea why the video is displaying when calling Linphone for windows but not when calling my proof of concept that makes use of Linphone for browser?***

This is my first question on https://stackoverflow.com/  If you have any pointers on improving this question please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This morning I posted the same question with the linphone developers mailing list.  I received a reply, which when implemented solved my problem.

**Link to the mailing list with the reply.** http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/linphone-developers/2015-05/msg00086.html

**Basically, now that the plugin had support for H263, I had to enable the codec.**

Enabling the H263 codec in my proof of concept.

```
core.enablePayloadType ( core.videoCodecs[2], true );
```